# How to configure DNS nameservers for Ubuntu cloud machines non-interactively?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ubuntu-12.04

I want to setup custom nameservers for my Ubuntu cloud instances (which have static IPs). When I try to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`, I see that it gets overwritten on reboot.

If I try to set it in `/etc/network/interfaces` it works, but this would is not friendly to script. Is there a easier way to script this so that the setting remains persistent across reboots?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resolvconf` command to overwrite/delete/update the nameserver. Check the following page for more details:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/resolvconf.8.html